# Scala: Find all strings of length up to n in regular language

Tags: regex, scala, regular-language

I have a (possibly infinite) regular language which I describe with a regular expression. From this regular language I want to obtain all strings of length up to n, using scala. Some quick googling tells me there are some libraries out there that can help me. Before using an external library I want to know if this is something that is easy (as in something a decent programmer can implement in under 15 minutes) to do myself in Scala. If not, are there some good libraries that you can recommend for this?

To make what I want more concrete. Suppose I have the language `A*B*` and my `n` is 3, I then want the strings `"", "A", "B", "AA", "AB", "BB", "AAA", "AAB", "ABB", "BBB"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

### Edits

- 26Nov, 4:30pm - added **iterator-based** version to reduce runtime and memory consumption. Seq-based version of canonic is at the bottom under (1)
- 26Nov, 2:45pm - added working **seq-based** version for canonic, non working old version of canonic is at the bottom (2)

### Approach

- Canonically generate all words possible for a given alphabet up to length `n`.
- Filter the generated words by a regular expression (your regular language in that case)

### Code

```
object SO {

  import scala.annotation.tailrec
  import scala.collection.{AbstractIterator, Iterator}
  import scala.util.matching.Regex

  def canonic(alphabet: Seq[Char], n: Int): Iterator[String] =
    if (n < 0) Iterator.empty
    else {
      val r: IndexedSeq[Iterator[String]] = for (i <- 1 to n)
        yield new CanonicItr(alphabet, i)
      r.reduce(_ ++ _)
    }

  private class CanonicItr(alphabet: Seq[Char], width: Int) extends AbstractIterator[String] {
    val aSize = alphabet.size
    val alph = alphabet.toVector
    val total = aSizePower(width)

    println("total " + total)

    private var pos = 0L

    private def aSizePower(r: Int): Long = scala.math.pow(aSize, r).toLong

    def stringFor(id: Long): String = {
      val r = for {
        i <- (0 until width).reverse
        // (738 / 10^0) % 10 = 8
        // (738 / 10^1) % 10 = 3
        // (738 / 10^2) % 10 = 7
        charIdx = ((id / (aSizePower(i))) % aSize).toInt
      } yield alph(charIdx)
      r.mkString("")
    }

    override def hasNext: Boolean = pos < total

    override def next(): String = {
      val s = stringFor(pos)
      pos = pos + 1
      s
    }
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // create all possible words with the given alphabet 
    val canonicWordSet = canonic(Seq('a', 'b', 'c'), 8)

    // formal regular language definition
    val languageDef: Regex = "a*b".r

    // determine words of language by filtering the canocic set. 
    val wordsOfLanguage = canonicWordSet.filter(word => languageDef.pattern.matcher(word).matches)

    println(wordsOfLanguage.toList)
  }
}
```

#### 1) Working version of `canonic` but with high memory requirements

```
object SO {

  import scala.util.matching.Regex

  /**
    * Given a sequence of characters (e.g. Seq('a', 'b', 'c') )
    * generates all combinations up to lneght of n (incl.).
    * 
    * @param alphabet sequence of characters
    * @param n is the max length
    * @return all combinations of up to length n. 
    */
  def canonic(alphabet:Seq[Char], n: Int): Seq[String] = {
    def combination( input: Seq[String], chars: Seq[Char]) = {
      for {
        i <- input
        c <- chars
      } yield (i+c)
    }

    @tailrec
    def rec(left: Int, current: Seq[String], accum: Seq[String] ) : Seq[String] = {
      left match {
        case 0 => accum
        case _ => {
          val next = combination( current, alphabet )
          rec( left-1, next, accum ++ next )
        }     
      }
    }

    rec(n, Seq(""), Seq(""))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    // create all possible words with the given alphabet 
    val canonicWordSet= canonic( Seq('a', 'b', 'c'), 3)

    // formal regular language definition
    val languageDef: Regex = "a*b".r

    // determine words of language by filtering the canocic set. 
    val wordsOfLanguage = canonicWordSet.filter( word => languageDef.pattern.matcher(word).matches )

    println( wordsOfLanguage.toList )
  }
}
```

#### 2) Non working version of `canonic` not working correctly

```
def canonic(alphabet:Seq[Char], n: Int): Iterator[String] = {
  for {
    i <- (0 to n).iterator
    combi <- alphabet.combinations(i).map(cs => cs.mkString)
  } yield combi
}
```

Comment: Just have seen an error .... canonic(..) does not generate all pairs! Will correct it ....

Answer (score 0):

I have not completely understood your meaning, is this OK?

```
scala> def generator(chars: Seq[Char], n: Int): Iterator[String] = 
     |   (0 to n).iterator flatMap (i => (chars flatMap (_.toString*i) mkString) combinations i)
generator: (chars: Seq[Char], n: Int)Iterator[String]

scala> 

scala> generator("AB", 3) toList
res0: List[String] = List("", A, B, AA, AB, BB, AAA, AAB, ABB, BBB)

scala> generator("ABC", 3) toList
res1: List[String] = List("", A, B, C, AA, AB, AC, BB, BC, CC, AAA, AAB, AAC, ABB, ABC, ACC, BBB, BBC, BCC, CCC)
```

Comment: Not correct. E.g. CA, CB is missing for `generator("ABC", 3) toList`.